# Combining methods that are the same but take in different variables

Tags: c#, variables, methods, constructor, repeat

I have a method I use to take in a number and return the number in a notation format. I'm using doubles, floats, and ints in my code so I have three of the same methods written with only the intake variable different for them. Is there a way I can get the same effect with only 1 method?

To try and explain further. I want to create a method that accepts multiple variable types to it. Instead of the method calling for a double, I'd like it to accept a variable if it's an int, a float, or a double without casting. Right now I have 3 copies of the same method, each one accepting a different variable. I don't want to change all the variables I'm using to doubles for other reasons within the code.

Is there any way I can use one method that accepts all three variable types instead of having 3, each one accepting only one variable type.

```
public string NotationMethod(double x, string y)
{
    if (x > 1000)
    {
        var exponent = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(x)));
        var mantissa = x / Math.Pow(10, exponent);
        return mantissa.ToString("F2") + "e" + exponent;
    }
    return x.ToString("F0");
}

public string NotationMethod(int x, string y)
{
    if (x > 1000)
    {
        var exponent = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(x)));
        var mantissa = x / Math.Pow(10, exponent);
        return mantissa.ToString("F2") + "e" + exponent;
    }
    return x.ToString("F0");
}

public string NotationMethod(float x, string y)
{
    if (x > 1000)
    {
        var exponent = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(x)));
        var mantissa = x / Math.Pow(10, exponent);
        return mantissa.ToString("F2") + "e" + exponent;
    }
    return x.ToString("F0");
}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] post to explain why just `double` version is not enough?

Comment: Hi there,

In my code, I'm using int, float, and double variables. I don't want to change all variables to doubles so I'm using these three methods as a catch all to make sure they are all accepted when I use this method on them. I'm wondering if there's a cleaner simpler way to code this.

Comment: I don't get your comment at all... What sort of variables you are talking in  "to change all variables to doubles" ? In any case please [edit] the post instead of adding comment.

Comment: Why don't you simply call method `NotationMethod(double, string)` from withing other two methods? It will reduce repetition of the code. All three methods have identical implementation (`var` is substituted by `double` during compilation). It is not possible in `C#` to create a single method that will substitute these three methods.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are using `Math.Floor()` in each case. I think you can simply use the method with first parameter `Double` data type. You will just need to convert the inputs to `Double` while calling the method.

Comment: Clearly I don't get something here. Both question and answer talk about some sort of "conversion" that is necessary...

Comment: OK I will keep this in mind! Is there any way for a method to do this automatically? I'm just trying to always learn better ways to keep my code as simple and clean as possible.